# Spring MVC 3.0.6 Getting hold of the controller and action name

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

Is there a way to get the controller and action name currently ( or about to ) executing ?

I am interested in getting this primarily in an Interceptor so I can perform logic depending on action.

Grails for example offers this as params.controller and params.action

Anything similar? Could not find anything on the web.

Spring MVC 3.0.6 ( found this [Spring MVC : What is the best way to pass the controller + action name to the view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186386/spring-mvc-what-is-the-best-way-to-pass-the-controller-action-name-to-the-vi) but it was for version 3.1 )

Thanks!

Comment: No one? There has to be a way!?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an aspect to get the method name from `joinPoint.getSignature().getName()`, and that can be added to the `Model` as an `Attribute`.  The `Controller` name is probably also in there somewhere.

Comment: Its an object available in a Spring Aspect.  Here's a starting point: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw-first-example